# MYSQL PHP update db table information through html form

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to update information in my db but am having no luck and no error messages.

Here is the page code (the pid or post_id is in the URL):

```
<?php
include('page with functions.php');


if (isset($_GET['pid'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['body'])){

if (edit_post($_GET['pid'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['body'])){
header("Location: blog_edit.php?pid={$_GET['pid']}");
}else{
header("Location: some location.php");
}

die();

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Blog Edit</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <?php

if (isset($_GET['pid']) ===false || valid_pid($_GET['pid']) === false){
echo 'Invalid post ID';
}else{
$post = get_post($_GET['pid']);

    ?>

<h2><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h2>


<hr />

<p><?php echo $post['body']; ?></p>

<hr />



    <form action="" method="post">
         <p>
<label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo $post['title']; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <textarea name="body" rows="20" cols="60"><?php echo $post['body']; ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Edit Post" />
        </p>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the function (the pid or post_id is in the URL):

```
// edits a blog entry
function edit_post($title, $body){

$title = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($title));
$body = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($body)));

mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` (`post_title`, `post_body`) SET `post_title` = '{$title}' AND `post_body` = '{body}' WHERE `post_id` = {$pid}");

}
```

Any help would be great thanks!
FYI I am new to PHP MYSQL so please be kind.

Comment: `mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` (`post_title`, `post_body`) SET `post_title` = '{$title}' AND `post_body` = '{$body}' WHERE `post_id` = {$pid}");` I think you missed the dollar before `body`.

Comment: A dumb mistake, but still no such luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (edit_post($_GET['pid'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['body'])){
header("Location: blog_edit.php?pid={$_GET['pid']}");
}else{
header("Location: some location.php");
}
```

You're passing three arguments in the function call, but the function definition has only 2 arguments.

```
function edit_post($title, $body){

$title = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($title));
$body = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($body)));

mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` (`post_title`, `post_body`) SET `post_title` = '{$title}' AND `post_body` = '{body}' WHERE `post_id` = {$pid}");

}
```

Also, return a boolean from the function.

```
function edit_post($pid, $title, $body){

$title = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($title));
$body = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($body)));

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` (`post_title`, `post_body`) SET `post_title` = '{$title}' AND `post_body` = '{body}' WHERE `post_id` = {$pid}");

echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Added the pid and still no luck.

Comment: what does mysql_query return? Could you `echo` the same and post the result?

Comment: Sorry Im very new to this, I have been going off of tutorials..how would i do that.

Comment: Nothing happened, it preformed the redirect from the headers.  I removed if (edit_post($_GET['pid'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['body'])){
header("Location: blog_edit.php?pid={$_GET['pid']}");
}else{
header("Location: index.php");
} and when i clicked submit, it reloaded the page and it was blank.

Comment: From the PHP manual... if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} Try that in your edit_post function in place of echo $result. At least you'll see if the Update is working.